# int x = ++n + n++; returns an unexpected value

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, post-increment, pre-increment

According to the concept of pre-increment and post-increment operator the output of the following code should be (8+8) = 16, but in the compiler it is evaluated to 17. Please explain with steps.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 7;
    int x = ++n + n++;
    cout << x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Comment: Change `int x = ++n + n++;` to `++n; int x = n + n; n++;`

Answer (score 4):

> following code should be (8+8) = 16

That's not correct.

---

> Please explain with steps.

This expression:

> ```
> ++n
> ```

Modifies `n`.

This expression:

> ```
> n++
> ```

Modifies `n`.

This expression:

> ```
> ++n + n++
> ```

Has two modifications on the same variable that are *unsequenced* in relation to each other. Hence, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Since the bahviour is undefined, there is no output that "should" or "shouldn't" be.

Comment: Is this still UB in C++17?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Yes, it is still UB.

Comment: Thanks. [This page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) has all the rules, including the new ones. `i = ++i + 2;` is instead well defined.